# How to see workflow variables when debugging WF 4 Workflow Service

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation-4, visual-studio-debugging

How can I see the current value of workflow variables when debugging a WF 4 Workflow Service (hosted in IIS 7.5 / AppFabric)?

I attach Visual Studio 2010 to w3wp.exe but when a breakpoint on an activity is hit, only the following parameters are shown in the "Locals" debugger window:

- isPriming
- typeIslandArguments
- debugInfo

Trying to add a workflow variable manually to "Watch" results in "The name 'xyz' does not exist in the current context".

Am I doing something wrong? Is my environment messed up (a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine with VS 2010 and VS 11 Beta installed - is it possible that VS 11 broke something)?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the values of the variables and more with the built-in IIS management console.  As @Vivek stated you could also build your own custom tracking mechanism but that doesn't sound like what you're needing here.

Essentially you just need to turn the logging up a bit so it's more diagnostic and you will be able to see that information on the live running workflows that are running in AppFabric.

Comment: This is indeed what I used as a workaround. So I take it's not possible to do VS debugging on AppFabric WF Services. Pity.

Comment: That is correct currently and likely for the foreseeable future.  I would say that the primary reason for this is because the "variables" are actually a lot more complex than standard fields or properties, and they aren't visible in that manner either.  The values must take into consideration the Context that they are running in and are persistable.  I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Is your requirment to do analysis of value for certain variable, then you can also use custom tracking.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue by repairing Visual Studio.

*Control Panel->Programs And Features->VS 20XX->Repair*

The problem was probably caused by the installation order of appfabric,vs and additional tools.
More information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157687.aspx).